# Grails support in Intellij Community Edition

Tags: grails

How can i create a Grails project in IntelliJ Community Edition, Which need AnjularJs, JQuery modules and InMemory DB like JavaDB

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! (P.s: [here are some tutorials](https://grails.org/tutorials))

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That is a limitation of the Community Edition.

Comment: i think this is only true for grails 2.x. In the 3.x version you have basic support in the community edition, because it is "just" a gradle project. But you have no "Grails View" or specific support for the grails commands.